# C# Text Matching HTML

Tags: c#, regex, string, xml-parsing

I'm trying to interact with a really crappy "web-service" (cleverly disguised as simple aspx page...) but I don't control the page so I can't tweak the output so I'm stuck with it.  The format is always the same like this:

```
<b>
   <a href=\"http://www.google.com/\" target=\"_blank\">Google Inc</a>
</b>
<br />123 North Main
<br />Hume, ACT
<br />(999) 888-8888
```

So, I need to parse out the `URL`, `Name`, `Address`, `City`, `State`, and `Phone`? It's not really properly formed XML so I can't use XML parser, and RegEx seems painfully nasty, so am I stuck with `String.Match` and `IndexOf` etc?

Thanks for your suggestions...
James

Answer (score 2):

you can use a `HTML` parser to parse the page, [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), is a free and robust  one. Or you can use any `XQuery` processor for .Net, Please have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) to see the drawbacks of using `regex` for parsing html pages

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a regex, assuming the html elements remain static. My solution would be to find the index of the `<b>, </b>, and <br />` elements, then just take substrings from one index to the next. For example

```
int bStartIndex = html.IndexOf("<b>");
int bEndIndex = html.IndexOf("</b>)");
int urlSize = bEndIndex - bStartIndex - 3;
string url = html.Substring(bStartIndex + 3, urlSize);
```

And yes, this method is a crude hack, however, given the circumstances of a "really crappy web-service", I think it's a fair and straight up solution, albeit tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the past i tried many other ways to use framework methods  to get the values inside. But that format is too customized, so i think the only ways is loop every line in the response, and anytime you get a  value it will have the url. Anytime you start to read 
 string in the line, well it will be the address, next the city-state and so on.
For any reason, the order of properties of the objects arrive in different order lines, well the code will fail.
I recommend you (if it's possible) at least return from the service a JSON format which is easy to deserialize. In other case you should build your own deserializer to get the data as you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Regex.Replace (if this is always formatted exactly the same way) like this:

```
string crappyXML = 
"<b>
   <a href=\"http://www.google.com/\" target=\"_blank\">Google Inc</a>
</b>
<br />123 North Main
<br />Hume, ACT
<br />(999) 888-8888";

string betterXML = Regex.Replace(crappyXML, "</b><br />", "</b><br>");
```

(You may need to account for that space if there is a space between )

Then your betterXML looks like this:

```
"<b>
   <a href=\"http://www.google.com/\" target=\"_blank\">Google Inc</a>
</b>
<br>123 North Main
<br />Hume, ACT
<br />(999) 888-8888";
```

Then you can do another Regex:

```
betterXML = Regex.Replace(betterXML, "<br />", "</br><br>");
```

Which would make it look like this:

```
"<b>
   <a href=\"http://www.google.com/\" target=\"_blank\">Google Inc</a>
</b>
<br>123 North Main
</br><br>Hume, ACT
</br><br>(999) 888-8888";
```

Then just do this:

```
betterXML += "</br>";
```

to close the last tag.

AGAIN, none of my `Regex.Replace` code accounts for white space. You will have to add that in.

From there, you should be able to use the XML parser and loop through to get your data.

I hope that helps! Let me know any questions.